# Oracle Apex 19 - Classic Report pagination is fetching only 15 rows

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Apex 19. For a Classic Report Region the pagination is fetching only 15 rows of 22. When clicking on *Next* button all the visualized rows and relative headings are deleted. I can see only the name of the region. The query is very simple. I'm reading only a table without any external join nor functions. The select list have less then 15 elements. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the Classic Report region attributes as follows:

1. Layout / Number of rows = 1000
2. Pagination / Type = No Pagination